# converting a string into parameter for GET request in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, url, python-requests

I am calling a GET API to retrieve some data. For get call I need to covert my keyword as

```
keyword = "mahinder singh dhoni"
```

into

```
caption%3Amahinder%2Ccaption%3Asingh%2Ccaption%3Adhoni
```

I am new to python and dont know the pythonic way. I am doing like this

```
caption_heading = "caption%3A"
caption_tail = "%2Ccaption%3A"

keyword = "mahinder singh dhoni"
x = keyword.split(" ")
new_caption_keyword = []
new_caption_keyword.append(caption_heading)
for data in x:
    new_caption_keyword.append(data)
    new_caption_keyword.append(caption_tail)

search_query = ''.join(new_caption_keyword)
search_query = search_query[:-13]

print("new transformed keyword", search_query)
```

Is there a better way to do this.I means this is kind of hard coding.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best to turn our original string into a list:

```
>>> keyword = "mahinder singh dhoni"
>>> keyword.split()
['mahinder', 'singh', 'dhoni']
```

Then your actual string looks like `caption:...,caption:...,caption:...`, that can be done with a join and a format:

```
>>> # if you're < python3.6, use 'caption:{}'.format(part)`
>>> [f'caption:{part}' for part in keyword.split()]
['caption:mahinder', 'caption:singh', 'caption:dhoni']
>>> ','.join([f'caption:{part}' for part in keyword.split()])
'caption:mahinder,caption:singh,caption:dhoni'
```

And finally you'll urlencode using `urllib.parse`:

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.quote(','.join([f'caption:{part}' for part in keyword.split()]))
'caption%3Amahinder%2Ccaption%3Asingh%2Ccaption%3Adhoni'
```

Answer (score 1):

so try this way,
instead of split you can replace " " empty space with `"%2Ccaption%3A"` and start your string with `"caption%3A"`

for 2.x:

```
>>> from urllib import quote
>>> keyword = "mahinder singh dhoni"
>>> quote(','.join(['caption:%s'%i for i in keyword.split()]))
```

for 3.x:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import quote
>>> keyword = "mahinder singh dhoni"
>>> quote(','.join(['caption:%s'%i for i in keyword.split()]))
```